# function is not getting updated value of variable from another function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

The value of variable `$jwtoken` in method `addNew()` is null. I want to pass `auth()` method value "some val" to `addNew()` method/function.

```
class Employees extends CI_Controller
{
    public $jwtoken = null;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
            
    public function auth() {
        if(condition is true){
           $this->jwtoken = 'val1';
        }
        else{
          $this->jwtoken = 'val2';
        }
        
    }
    
    public function addNew()
    {
        $this->auth();
        echo $this->jwtoken;
    }
    // ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

class Employees extends CI_Controller{

```
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function auth() {
       if(condition==true){
            return "some val";
        }else{
          return "some other val";
        }
  }

  public function addNew()
  {
     echo $this->auth();
    
  }
```

}

Your code is working fine in codeigniter 4. try removing constructor.

Comment: $Hashan please respond again based on question/post changes